# Use Python Fuzzy string matching library to match string between a list with 30 value and a given value and get the closest match in field calculator

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to get the closest match between different strings but 
The Function is limited to only 5 values to compare and I want to increase it to 30 value at least, any ideas how to work around this from ArcMap field calculator?

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
def SetMatchPercenage(query,v1,v2,v3,v4):
    choices = [v1,v2,v3,v4]
    result= process.extractOne(query, choices)
    return result
```

The output is the top match from the given values like this

> ('Barack H Obama', 95)

Comment: Could you explain more what you are trying to do? You want to compare values stored in 30 different fields in the attribute table?

Comment: You mention the "ArcMap field calculator" and have an ArcPy tag but it is not clear to me why you see this as a GIS rather than pure Python question that would be better researched/asked (without ArcGIS/ArcPy) at [so].

Comment: I have one table with 31 column I want to match the first column value with the other 30 in the same record. 

using this function is limited to only 5 variables I am trying to find a way to compare the rest variables

Comment: I dont Think there is a limitation on the number of arguments that can be used in the field calculator: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm "A Python function can be written to accept any number of input arguments". Could you add a screenshot of the attribut table?

Comment: The "given variable" is stored in a field?

Comment: The given Values are stored in fields yes.

The function I am using from fuzzy library itself can't take more than 5 variables.

Comment: According to the Fuzzy help:

query = 'Barack Obama'
choices = ['Barack H Obama', 'Barack H. Obama', 'B. Obama']
# Get a list of matches ordered by score, default limit to 5
process.extract(query, choices)
# [('Barack H Obama', 95), ('Barack H. Obama', 95), ('B. Obama', 85)]
 
# If we want only the top one
process.extractOne(query, choices)
# ('Barack H Obama', 95)

they mentioned that the default limit is 5 I have a concern if I used the function in the wrong way the results will not be accurate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think it would be easier to use Python and an UpdateCursor instead of the Field calculator:

[image]

Code:

```
import arcpy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

feature_class=r'C:\TEST.gdb\Points12345'

fields_to_look_in=['Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4','Field5','Field6'] #extend to all the fields you want to look in
matchfields=['Match','Best_Match'] #First field is the one to match and the result will be written to the second field

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class,fields_to_look_in+matchfields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[-1]=process.extractOne(row[-2], choices=list(row[:-2]))[0]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, BERA

I tend to use arc field calculator because I am using this code in a part of a model builder solution, but I think I could achieve that using a cursor like the one you provided in your code. 

Thanks,